# how to add a custom component in ssis

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm setting a new custom component in SSIS , after deploying the DLL it appears in the toolbox but the component still not working and I have this error :

> TITRE :  Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Impossible d'ajouter le composant à la tâche de flux de données.
>   Impossible d'initialiser le composant. Il existe un problème potentiel
>   dans la méthode ProvideComponentProperties.
>
> ------------------------------ INFORMATIONS SUPPLÉMENTAIRES :
>
> Erreur sur Data Flow Task 1 [PlanHome [66]] :
>   System.MissingMethodException: Méthode introuvable :
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'.
>   à NewPlan.Plan.ProvideComponentProperties()    à
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProvideComponentProperties(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper)
>
> ---
>
> Méthode introuvable :
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
>
> ------------------------------ BOUTONS :
>
> OK

**Translated Error**

> The component can not be added to the data flow task. Can not initialize the component. There is a potential problem in the ProvideComponentProperties method.

Comment: The .net framework that your SSDT is currently running on is the one that you need to develop your custom component it. Recompile it and redeploy it.

Comment: thank you @rvphx for your answer , but i tried to recompile and rebuilt many times but there is no progress. Is the problem with .Net framework ?